# Apple 2015 fiscal year accounting calendar

Tags: calendar

I was wondering if anyone know where I can acquire Apple's 2015 fiscal year accounting calendar?  I have tried a few varieties of search term and nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a link to the fiscal calendar in iTunes Connect at the bottom of the "Payments and Financial Reports" page.

I'd post a link here, but it might change in the future.